# Portable way to do case a ... z in C

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm using the following GCC extension to simplifying a big switch statement:

```
case 'a' ... 'z':
   ...
```

What's the proper/portable way to do this -- i.e., go through all the letters in a big switch -- or for this should a switch not be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `default` can be used for performing a task when none of the cases is true:

```
switch (x)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
        printf("%d\n", x);
        break;
    default:
        if (islower(x))
        {
            puts("alpha");
        }
        break;
}
```

Another way using the infamous `goto`:

```
if (islower(x))
    goto alpha;

switch (x)
{
    alpha:
        printf("alpha\n");
        break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
        printf("%d\n", x);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would 'go through all the letters in a big switch'.
Simply because the compiler (gcc or clang) will optimize this 'away' again.
If you compare following code:

```c
void func0(int x)
{
    switch( x )
    {
    case 'a':case 'b':case 'c':case 'd':case 'e':
    case 'f':case 'g':case 'h':case 'i':case 'j':
    case 'k':case 'l':case 'm':case 'n':case 'o':
    case 'p':case 'q':case 'r':case 's':case 't':
    case 'u':case 'v':case 'w':case 'x':case 'y':
    case 'z':
        func1(x);
        break;
    case 1001:
        func2(x);
        break;
    default:
        func3(x);
        break;
    }
}
```

with the assembly code generated (gcc)
(note: 97== 'a' and 122 == 'z'), it basically changed your code to
something similar to `if(c>'z')` and `if(c<'a')` :

```
func0:
        push    rbp
        .seh_pushreg    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        .seh_setframe   rbp, 0
        sub     rsp, 32
        .seh_stackalloc 32
        .seh_endprologue
        mov     DWORD PTR 16[rbp], ecx
        cmp     DWORD PTR 16[rbp], 122
        jg      .L2
        cmp     DWORD PTR 16[rbp], 97
        jge     .L3
        jmp     .L4
.L2:
        cmp     DWORD PTR 16[rbp], 1001
        je      .L5
        jmp     .L4
.L3:
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR 16[rbp]
        call    func1
        jmp     .L6
.L5:
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR 16[rbp]
        call    func2
        jmp     .L6
.L4:
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR 16[rbp]
        call    func3
        nop
.L6:
        nop
        add     rsp, 32
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

so the resulting assembly code is both optimized for speed and size.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all cases 'a' to 'z' (all lower case alphabets) to have the same effect then you can do the following

```
#include <ctype.h>

if(isalpha(c) && islower(c))
{
        //..Do Whatever... 
}
```

Comment: `islower` by itself should be enough as `isalpha` is essentially `islower || isupper`

Comment: @user -- I see, and if it's in a switch? Or is it suggested if the switch is more than X items (5?) to use something else instead?

Comment: @David542 - No, this is instead of a switch